# Parse Server and MongoDB basics

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, database, mongodb

I am writing an android restaurant delivery application, that sends customer orders to a back-end and receive push notifications. 
I am thinking about using Parse Server which uses MongoDB, instead of using a relational database. The database will be hosted on Back4App (which is a very useful development tool for Parse server back-end).

The database system must be able to receive data from the android application and manage that data and send queries, also I need to send push notifications from the server to the application.

Now that you understand what I aim to do, I would appreciate if someone answered the following questions :

1. How good do I need to be in JavaScript ? in order to store and
   manage data in Parse Server ?
2. How to write queries in Parse Server ? What programming languages I
   need to know ?
3. since I am a beginner, is it hard to learn everything about Parse
   Server in 3 weeks ?
4. I know that MongoDB does not use tables or SQL, how does MongoDB
   work exactly with Parse Server ? Do I need to know a lot about MongoDB
   before attempting to use Parse Server?
5. what is Node.js exactly? is this any different from JavaScript ?

I am doing a Senior Project and I would really appreciate the help of the community. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If your only client is an Android app, you don't need to know much Javascript or node.js. There are guides for how to install and set up Parse Server that don'trequire programming.  If you want a web client or server side code then that's a different story. In my experience not much knowledge of MongoDB is needed either but that may depend on your host. I use Atlas, which has pretty good tools.  Some familiarity with JSON would be helpful.

I don't know if Parse has a Kotlin SDK or if you're planning to write your app in Java or Kotlin but you'll need to know one of those well..

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. I aim to develop an android application using Java in Android Studio and a desktop application using IntelliJ IDEA, these are my 2 clients. I am a beginner and I have never used a Backend before for my app, but basically I need to let my app send data to the hosted database. In order to achieve that, do I need server side code ? (I am confused if I need it or not) and can I build the entire database on Back4app website ?

Comment: My clients are : an android application and a java desktop application using Intellij IDEA. I have a stupid question (I am a beginner), that I am very confused about, what does exactly a server side code do ? and why do I need it ?

Comment: I know java very well, javascript and currently learning JSON and I know nothing about Kotlin. Please correct me if I am wrong : I read that Parse server uses Mongo DB and REST API ( which I need to learn). Mongo DB  uses CRUD and JSON to build queries and  collections with documents. According to the Parse documentation : Parse uses it's own query language which is referred as "cloud code".

Comment: You do not need to write any server-side code unless you want triggers or something like that.  You will need to learn the Parse Java SDK, but you don't need to know about the underlying mechanisms if you don't care to.  Just learn how the API works. You may need to do a little database tuning, such as creating indexes.  This will require knowing how to connect to MongoDB and run commands. This is also one area where JSON knowledge will be useful, as well as if you ever want to look directly at your data records, as they'll be stored in JSON format.  I don't know anything about Back4app.

Answer (score 1):

I hope is everything well with you!

Back4App is a backend-as-a-service which prepares an App in a few minutes for you to start to work.

You can use Javascript in the Cloud Code environment which you can deploy .js codes to help you for complex logic or to these codes become available to all mobile/web/IoT environments instantly. Read more about it [here](https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/get-started/cloud-functions).

Also, the Cloud Code already configured a Node.js environment, you don't need to configure again.

The default entry point for your Cloud Code is at `./cloud/main.js`.

You can learn using guides regarding Android Parse SDK Android, check below:

https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/parse-android-sdk

If you want to host a web app in Back4App, you can follow the guide below:

https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/node-js-web-server

Comment: Hello everything is fine, thank you for your reply.

Comment: I am only developing a android application using android studio and java, I want to develop a database for my app (using Parse Server and Mongo DB) and host it online.

Comment: Here's where I am confused :
I am aware of Parse documentation which describes some kind of cloud code to build queries (is this code specific to Parse server ?) . However Parse server is based on Mongo DB, which I know that it uses JSON and CRUD. So what do I need to know exactly ? do I use JSON and CRUD to build queries to achieve my purpose ? or do I need Javascript and Parse query language ? or do I need all of these including : javascript , cloud code, JSON and CRUD ? I am sorry if this question seems stupid, but I am a complete beginner when it come to developing back ends.

Comment: My Purpose : I want my app to be able to send and receive data from an online database using Parse Server. However I can't seem to make a list of what I need to learn, in order to achieve this.

Comment: No problems regarding your questions. Yes, you're right, because Parse Server uses Mongo DB as a database, but you don't need to be aware of Mongo DB syntaxes, because the SDK will handle this for you. You only need to know about the SDK that you want to use, for example, Android SDK.

Comment: As I said, Cloud Code can be used if you need to apply a complex logic or you want to share the same code between different technologies, but it is according to your usage.

Comment: You can find an example of CRUD to each technology using the API Reference at Back4App website.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, it was helpful for setting me on the path to learn Parse Server

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind, as I am preparing my backend on Back4app. I ran across something called the restful API, which If i am not mistaken, is a way to send data over HTTP. I am developing a menu application which need to send items to the database, my question is Do I need restful API ? or the Parse Server SDK is enough to achieve my purpose ?  @nataliec